# nn.MSELoss inputs dimension mismatch problem

Tags: python, tensor, torch, loss-function, mse

I recently started learning how to use torch but when I was dealing with the sequential data. For example, the training x (input) is a tensor with shape ([1, 60, 278]), while the training y (target) has the shape ([1, 278]). The batch size is simply 1. Can I directly use the code below to calculate MSE?

```
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
mse = criterion(input, target)
```

I have no idea why sometimes it returned no error but sometimes it returned error: Please ensure they have the same size.
return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)

Do I need to duplicate target so that the dimension of target can match input?
I also found there are a few parameters in the function, say 'reduction', 'size_average', 'reduce'. Would they be helpful in dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The function `MSELoss` is defined by `MSELoss = lambda x, y: torch.mean((x - y)**2)` (with the reduction mean that is the default behavior).
Here you are trying to apply the minus operator `-` on two tensors of different shapes. A priori it is prohibited BUT pytorch is convenient and will tried to change the tensors to have compatible shapes. Here he sees that the 1rst and 3rd dimension axis of `input` are the same as the axis of `target` but the second axis doesn't exist in the later tensor. In this case, pytorch will repeat 60 times the rows of the `targets` to match the good shape `shape(1, 60, 278)` before applying the function. But it may not be what you need!

In your case you probably need to compute a single-vector representation of your sequence using a model in order to have a predictions of shape `shape(1, 278)` then you can compute your criterion: `criterion(model(inputs), target)` and avoid duplication of rows.

Comment: Thx, Valen. Such a great explanation! Can we understand in this way (my question statement) that we are actually calculating the MSE of a regression to a hyperplane/subspace, analogue to the regression to a horizontal line in one dimensional case?

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a linear model - linear models define lines or hyperplanes. A neural network is a non-linear model (e.g. it has non-linear operations like `x_out = min(0, x_in)`), so I don't think it can be described as analogous to linear regression. Regarding the MSE loss, that should be computed between the output of the model and the target, e.g. `output = model(input); mse_loss = nn.MSELoss()(output, target)`. The function expects `output` and `target` to be the same shape.